# Regex to not match expression when before equal sign?

Tags: regex, vim

```
foo = bar
foo        = bar
bar = foo
bar = foo asdfghjk
```

Is there a way to match every `foo` that is NOT on the left of an equal sign, so in this case the last two? I've tried:

```
(foo)([^=])
```

But that doesn't work. I'm not that good with regex, I don't know what to do from here.

Also, I am trying to pattern match in vim. I don't know if that makes a difference. I am aware the parentheses have to be escaped with `\`.

Comment: Try [`foo(?!\s*=)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ib0iZw/2/)

Comment: I may be oversimplifying but wouldn't `g/=\s\+foo` work. Or `%s/=\s\+foo/replacement/g` if replacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
:g/\vfoo(.*\=)@!/
```

Vim test:

[image]

The `g`lobal pattern

- `\v` - sets the very magic mode to avoid overescaping
- `foo` - a `foo` string
- `(.*\=)@!` - Vim-style classic negative lookahead that means that there can't be a `=` after any 0 or more chars (but line break chars) as many as possible.